# Error connecting to Snowflake through Java JDBC with PEM file

Tags: java, encryption, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-connector

I need to connect to Snowflake using Java using Key File in format P8

```
class JustTheCode {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
    String path = "/<path>/app_rsa_key.p8";
    String passphrase = "myKey";//System.getenv("PRIVATE_KEY_PASSPHRASE");
    bcParcer(path,passphrase);
}

private static PrivateKey bcParcer(String keyFilePath, String password)
    throws IOException, OperatorCreationException, PKCSException, Exception {
    PEMParser pemParser = new PEMParser(new FileReader(Paths.get(keyFilePath).toFile()));
    PKCS8EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo encryptedPrivateKeyInfo = (PKCS8EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo) pemParser.readObject();
    pemParser.close();
    InputDecryptorProvider pkcs8Prov = new JceOpenSSLPKCS8DecryptorProviderBuilder().build(
        password.toCharArray());
    JcaPEMKeyConverter converter = new JcaPEMKeyConverter().setProvider(
        BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
    PrivateKeyInfo decryptedPrivateKeyInfo = encryptedPrivateKeyInfo.decryptPrivateKeyInfo(
        pkcs8Prov);
    PrivateKey privateKey = converter.getPrivateKey(decryptedPrivateKeyInfo);
    System.out.println(privateKey);
    return privateKey;
}
```

}

When I run the code, I'm getting the error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.org.bouncycastle.pkcs.PKCSException: unable to read encrypted data: 1.2.840.113549.1.5.3 not available: requires PBE parameters
    at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.org.bouncycastle.pkcs.PKCS8EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo.decryptPrivateKeyInfo(Unknown Source)
    at configmgmt.snowflake.reader.impl.JustTheCode.bcParcer(PrivateKeyReader.java:122)
    at configmgmt.snowflake.reader.impl.JustTheCode.main(PrivateKeyReader.java:102)
Caused by: net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.org.bouncycastle.operator.OperatorCreationException: 1.2.840.113549.1.5.3 not available: requires PBE parameters
    at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.org.bouncycastle.openssl.jcajce.JceOpenSSLPKCS8DecryptorProviderBuilder$1.get(Unknown Source)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: requires PBE parameters
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.PBEWithMD5AndDESCipher.engineInit(PBEWithMD5AndDESCipher.java:186)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher.implInit(Cipher.java:867)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:929)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1299)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1236)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Parameters missing
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.PBES1Core.init(PBES1Core.java:214)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.PBEWithMD5AndDESCipher.engineInit(PBEWithMD5AndDESCipher.java:220)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.PBEWithMD5AndDESCipher.engineInit(PBEWithMD5AndDESCipher.java:184)
    ... 8 more
```

I am searching but in the documentation there is no information about this configuration:     **Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: requires PBE parameters**

Comment: thanks, yes is something like that: -----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
................................/EO/BzIYbeK7YF2HLOO5LTA3/vtRqqyB
0msrCvdErtC5di23AyfGUhEU9IqaGW/FsJs20YShK48R4FAfkd+ttsBDkx9dQoU6
H5BEvN7iyu2aeLj/GLT/IXVRzXsZ02uWH/PSAkI9g0Ff2mn028nBtwb5Xk3hE57n
3GQbLu1r0Il6lyC2...........
-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----

Comment: No, I can't, the company can fire me :(

Comment: I checked the key with: openssl rsa -in app_rsa_key.p8 -pubout and the response is: 

-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
......pM0AOY1w4Glf5JVk3ZILIAdDG51IQOXtYuirCmyk1mYQr5hRIVTHlZ/s5kREh5LB
hepnuXpLicszjPOeNb502U+ZWNBN/7H10zbGVjeVWMgJc7AXAtE/OOTf4cEDHHKL
WwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----

Comment: Try to test the key/pair using [SnowSQL](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowsql-start.html#using-key-pair-authentication-key-pair-rotation) and see if they work.

Comment: After the psvm i'm using Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the fix changing the imports:

Previously:

```
import net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs.PrivateKeyInfo;
import net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMParser;
import net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.org.bouncycastle.openssl.jcajce.JcaPEMKeyConverter;
import net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.org.bouncycastle.openssl.jcajce.JceOpenSSLPKCS8DecryptorProviderBuilder;
import net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.org.bouncycastle.operator.InputDecryptorProvider;
import net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.org.bouncycastle.operator.OperatorCreationException;
import net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.org.bouncycastle.pkcs.PKCS8EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo;
import net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.org.bouncycastle.pkcs.PKCSException;
```

new:

```
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs.PrivateKeyInfo;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMParser;
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.jcajce.JcaPEMKeyConverter;
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.jcajce.JceOpenSSLPKCS8DecryptorProviderBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.operator.InputDecryptorProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.operator.OperatorCreationException;
import org.bouncycastle.pkcs.PKCS8EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo;
import org.bouncycastle.pkcs.PKCSException;
```

And the pom:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcprov-ext-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <version>1.70</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <version>1.70</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides having correct imports as in the accepted answer, it's also worth checking if the **Security provider** registered from the **Snowflake jdbc driver** is not saved in the Java Security Providers, as it contains different parameters and amount of them - for me it was:

- **2727** parameters for *net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider*
- **2944** parameters for *org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider*

Checking Bouncy Castle Security Provider:

```
Security.getProvider("BC"); //or Security.getProvider(BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
```

Removing existing and registering a new Bouncy Castle Provider from the **bcprov-ext-jdk15on** library:

```
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;

Security.removeProvider("BC");
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
```